# How to make container div "pointer-events:none" but content clickable...?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

i have some setup... where tool tip appears on hover... so i have to put tool tip and anchor tags in same div... tool tips pointer events set to none.. but i cant set pointer events of container div to none because then Hover event is not detected... but i want the underlying element below tool tip to be clickable... please help me out (if possible) without java script... i have set up the dummy scenario below... also including code pen link.... and yeah... positions are not changeable...in my case the underlying div is partially visible as shown in this code below.. and i want it to be clickable/ fire alert function... yeah if there is other way by changing composition of UN-ordered list.. and separating it from that container please let me know... but tool tip should be visible on hover on switch...

```
        <html>

        <head>

    <style>


    .menudescription{
       float: left;
        width: 150px;
        height: 30px;

        text-align: center;
        background-color: #A1BA94;


        margin: 20px 0px 0px 12px;

        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 25px;
        font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
        color: white;
        border: solid white 2px;
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;

    }

    ul li {
        list-style-type:none
    }


    #menulist{
        clear: both;
        width: 230px;
        height: 342px;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 5%;
        z-index: 1000;


    }



    .menulistitem{
        clear: both;
        height: 60px;
            width: 60px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color: #A1BA94;
        margin: 2px;
        padding-top: 4px;

    }

    .menulistitem:hover + .menudescription{
        opacity: 1;
    }


    .underlyingdiv{
        height:200px;
        width:50px;
        background-color:red;
        position:relative;
        float:right;
        margin:20px 40px;
        display:block;


    }




        </style>


            </head>
    <body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul id="menulist">

           <li><div class="menulistitem" id="menuitem_showreel"><a href="#">switch
                </a></div> <div class="menudescription">tooltip</div></li>

           <li><div class="menulistitem" id="menuitem_showreel"><a href="#">switch
                </a></div> <div class="menudescription">tooltip</div></li>

           <li><div class="menulistitem" id="menuitem_showreel"><a href="#">switch
                    </a></div> <div class="menudescription">tooltip</div></li></ul>
        </div>

    <div class="underlyingdiv" onClick="myfunction()"></div>




        <script>
        function myfunction(){
        alert("hello");
    }
        </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

below is the code pen link...

http://codepen.io/theprash/pen/MKwWoN

Comment: You want link that says "switch" to be clickable and tooltip to show on hover? Seems to work for me on Chrome (on MacOSX). What browser / system are you using?

Comment: I would avoid reinventing the wheel and just use a cool tooltip plugin like [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/demos) to apply to your list items.

Comment: Yeah that works for me also... but i wanted underlying div to be clickable... Masooms solution worked for me :) thank you by the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.menudescription {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #A1BA94;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  color: white;
  border: solid white 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

#menulist {
  clear: both;
  width: 60px;
  height: 342px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 5%;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menulistitem {
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #A1BA94;
  margin: 2px;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.menulistitem:hover+.menudescription {
  opacity: 1;
}

.underlyingdiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 40px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul id="menulist">

      <li>
        <div class="menulistitem" id="menuitem_showreel"><a href="#">switch
            </a></div>
        <div class="menudescription">tooltip</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="menulistitem" id="menuitem_showreel"><a href="#">switch
            </a></div>
        <div class="menudescription">tooltip</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="menulistitem" id="menuitem_showreel"><a href="#">switch
                </a></div>
        <div class="menudescription">tooltip</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="underlyingdiv" onClick="myfunction()"></div>
</body>
```

The red container is clickable and the tooltip is visible on hover.

Things I do:

1. Added `position:relative` to `li`.
2. Removed floats to `div`s inside `li`s added below css to `.menudescription`

   ```
      position: absolute;
      right: 100%;
      top: 0;
   ```

This will help to position the `tooltip` relative to `li`

3. Override the `width` of `#menulist` to `60px` and remove `padding-left` for the same. This will make sure that the `red container` is clickable.

[Working Code pen](http://codepen.io/masoomulhaqs/pen/yeNymz?editors=110)

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted... :) Thank you!